# Laravel GuzzleHttp issue

Tags: php, laravel, api, laravel-5.1, guzzle

I need to use and API from example.com
I use Laravel as a framework and to get data with API in their docs I see this:

```
  curl https://api.example.com/api/AvailabilitySearch ^
 -H "Authorization: Bearer eyJ0ehsagdasjhgdashdgaOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJpc3Msjhdshjdasd7676N5c3RlbXMuY29tIn0.DBR5UPxxxxxxzxzxzxzxzxzxzxyzxyzxyzxyzyxzyxyzxyxxWQ_BkS1mzxw" ^
 -d VisitDate=2017-05-08 ^
 -d PartySize=2 ^
 -d ChannelCode=ONLINE
```

What I try to do is:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use GuzzleHttp;

class TestController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */

    public function test()
    {

        $client = new GuzzleHttp\Client();

        $res = $client->request('GET','https://example.com/api/AvailabilitySearch', [
        'headers' => [
        'Authorization' => 'Bearer eyJ0ehsagdasjhgdashdgaOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJpc3Msjhdshjdasd7676N5c3RlbXMuY29tIn0.DBR5UPxxxxxxzxzxzxzxzxzxzxyzxyzxyzxyzyxzyxyzxyxxWQ_BkS1mzxw',
      ],
        'form_params' => [
        'VisitDate' => '2017-05-24',
        'PartySize' => '2',
        'ChannelCode' => 'ONLINE',
      ],
    ]);

// You need to parse the response body
// This will parse it into an array
$res = json_decode($res->getBody(), true);

    dd ($res);    
    }


    public function index()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function show($id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function edit($id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function destroy($id)
    {
        //
    }
}
```

Now when I try to test i get:

```
BadMethodCallException in functions.php line 324:
Unknown method, request
```

How I can solve ths problem? How to use Guzzle instead cURL with Laravel framework? What is wrong in my code ... I just follow guzzle docs and API docs.

Comment: Post the stack trace

Comment: I don't think you can pass form params in a GET request, that would make this a POST request. Try changing the method to POST or try removing the form_params.

Comment: I again receive: BadMethodCallException in functions.php line 324:
Unknown method, request

Comment: I also try: $res = $client->post('htt ... " but then I get error: InvalidArgumentException in MessageFactory.php line 185:
No method is configured to handle the form_params config key

Comment: Any ideas why this code wont work

Comment: Late to the party but might help someone, when I got this error message, it was related with the Guzzle version, I needed update Guzzle to version 6 to be able to use this line: "$client->request(..."